# HP envy x360 13 ay-0008NA with ryzen 4500u won't wake up after suspend

Tags: suspend, 20.04, laptop, hp

I recently got an HP Envy x360 with the new ryzen 4500u CPU. After fixing a bunch of different issues and updating to kernel 5.7, there is a few bugs that remain. First, the laptop won't work after I suspend for more than 20 min. When trying to do so. the laptop opens to what was opened before closing the lid, but the cursor shows some kind of artifact and nothing is working.
Secondly, the microphone is not working, although this is much less of an issue for me and I can always get an external one later on.

Any tips for suspend issue?

Running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I had the same behavior on my Ryzen 7 5700U laptop, but it resolved itself when I upgraded to kernel 5.12.x. Could you give it a shot and update using the mainline tool to 5.12.x and see if it solves the suspend issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the 20 minutes part, but I wonder if this is related to hybrid sleep mode.

e.g. Laptop goes to sleep/suspend, then a while later it hibernates and flushes memory/state to disk.

It's possible that suspend/sleep is ok, but hibernate is causing issues.

I'm not sure if it's systemd that's responsible for this, but `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` seems to indicate that hybrid sleep and hibernation are enabled by default.

There may also be some hibernate-related settings in the gnome power management area that could be worth checking.

As a quick test, temporarily disabling hibernate completely may be worth trying to isolate the issue.

There's a bunch of GPU driver improvements in the 5.8 kernel as well (currently in RC stage): [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8-rc2/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8-rc2/)

Wish I could tell you something more useful, but mine hasn't been delivered yet. When it is, I'll probably run into the same issue(s) and will have good motivation to try to deal with it.

Comment: So my x360 w/ a 4700U arrived a few days ago, and I went straight to the 5.8.0-rc5 kernel (although I've gone back and tested 5.7.9.

I haven't left the lid closed to attempt suspend for a long period of time yet, but I have noticed one behavior that prevents me from getting further.  If I close the lid, the laptop never actually sleeps. I can hear the fan spinning at its lowest speed, and checking dmesg after re-opening the lid shows a few stacktraces related to attempting, but failing to suspend: https://gist.github.com/awatry/ef59659ba659e9633dbed3fc08d69221

Comment: Yup, if I leave it closed for a longer period of time (45 minutes or so), the fans are off, but if I peek between the body/screen I can see that the power LED is still lit up like the laptop is awake.  Opening the lid and trying to press various keys to "wake it up" doesn't work.  Had to hold the power button and force it to power down.

Comment: Based on the stack traces I'm seeing in dmesg, I've opened up a report on the drm/amd issues bug tracker, here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230

Comment: Thank you for all your effort! s2idle finally works for me with Ryzen 5 4500U after an upgrade with Kernel version 5.14.14 under Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

That is because suspend to RAM (S3) was replaced with "modern-standby" (S0ix).
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357421/830349) is my workaround on how to enable and enjoy S3 again on HP 15s-eq1009 with Ryzen 3 4300U. Hope it will be useful for you too.