# Laptop not waking from sleep

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, acer

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on an Acer Swift 3 laptop (SF314-42), and when I sleep/suspend the laptop, the screen is blank. Sometimes, when I suspend it for 10 seconds, then wake it, it works, but when I leave it for 5 mins or more, it won't wake, just a blank screen.

My specs are:

- Ryzen 5 4500U
- 8GB DDR4
- Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic

I tried to update the kernel and that didn't make a difference.

I did have a laptop with similar spec, but it was a Lenovo Ideapad and it didn't have these issues.

I tried another distro (Manjaro) and I had the same problem.

Comment: Does the power led on the side of your laptop turn off? I have no luck with my SF314-42 suspending properly under Ubuntu and Fedora. I was able to make it suspend under Windows 10 with a BIOS update. That's why I know that the led must turn off if it's suspended properly.

Comment: This isue is related to: https://askubuntu.com/q/1252302/1112981

Answer (score 5):

Update: Suspending started to work for me after upgrading to Linux Kernel 5.14.14 under Fedora. I did not test it under Ubuntu, but it should work now for Ubuntu too with Kernel 5.14.14. The version provides some fixes to s2idle ACPI driver. The power led on the side of the laptop turns off when suspended. Suspend-resume on lid close-open works promptly. `dmesg` log is now clean.

---

**Previous explanations and suggestions**:

The suspend does not work properly because of poor s2idle support. If you have BIOS 1.04 on your SF314-42, you can enable back s3 support in BIOS. For this, you will need to get into the advanced mode.

David Watson [summarized the instructions](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230#note_892624) as follows:

> I can confirm that the workaround reported here works on Acer Swift 3 with matching 1.04 BIOS and Ryzen 4700U. The key sequence required from the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HceE1Gk9Z8g) to enable advanced bios is:
>
> Boot into bios with the F2 key at the Acer screen.
> Once in BIOS, power off by holding down the power key.
> Once powered off, press:
>
> ```
> F4, 4, R, F, V
> F5, 5, T, G, B
> F6, 6, Y, H, N
> ```
>
> Power back on with the power key.
> Press F2 to enter BIOS.
> Now you are in advanced BIOS and there are hundreds of menu items.
> Go to AMD PBS.
> Scroll down to S3/Modern Standby Support.
> Select S3 Enable with the F5/F6 keys.
> F10 to Save and Exit.
>
> After doing this process, the suspend function works reliably for me on Fedora 34 Beta Desktop. Suspend would hang as described here on just about every Linux kernel I tested prior to this including: Ubuntu, Manjaro, Clear, etc. I'm going to test Ubuntu 21.04 next and I'll report what I find.

[image]

Comment: Upgrading to 5.14.21 worked for me, same Computer as the OP. To do that under Ubuntu, I had to use the mainline tool ([instructions](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2021/11/01/how-to-install-mainline-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-based-distribution/)).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling hibernation mode:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

If you want to revert to being able to use hibernation, run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: OP asked how to make hibernation work not how to turn it off.